# Call function from another script

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm programming a simple game (the first one I do on my own) in which basically there are two scoring goals, and when a player scores, I want to reset the position for all players to some coordinates.

I have a script attached to the goals, which detects collision with the ball, as follows:

Goal.js

```js
#pragma strict

function OnTriggerEnter2D (hitInfo : Collider2D) {
    if (hitInfo.name == "Ball")
    {
        var wallName = transform.name;
        GameManager.Score (wallName);
        hitInfo.gameObject.SendMessage ("ResetBall");

        //Here I need to call the ResetPlayer function
        PlayerControlHS.ResetPlayer();
    }
}
```

The following script is attached to the players

PlayerControlHS.js

```js
#pragma strict

var resetPosX : float;
var resetPosY : float;

//keys
var moveUp : KeyCode;
var moveLeft : KeyCode;
var moveRight : KeyCode;

var speed : int = 4;

function Update () {
    if (Input.GetKey(moveUp)) {
        rigidbody2D.velocity.y = speed;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(moveLeft)) {
        rigidbody2D.velocity.x = -speed;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKey(moveRight)) {
        rigidbody2D.velocity.x = speed;
    }
    else {
        rigidbody2D.velocity.x = 0;
    }
}

function ResetPlayer () {
    Debug.Log("I'm being called");
}
```

Both the goals and the players have a RigidBody 2D and a collider of some kind, as well as the ball.
I've gotten to get the function called as it is right now, but if I try to modify the position coordinates of a player, I enter a loop of death errors that when I fix one, I get another one.

That happens when I put this code in ResetPlayer():

```js
rigidbody2D.position.x = resetPosX;
rigidbody2D.position.y = resetPosY;
```

Mostly, the errors are because I need an object of type PlayerControlHS to access those fields. I've tried adding a variable of that type (and referencing it to each player) but it doesn't work because it tells me I need an object to access that variable... I don't know how to initialize it if I make it static.

How could I get it working?

EDIT: I'm thinking the best approach would be sending a message just like the ResetBall one, but it doesn't work (I think because the function is called from ball, object of another type and it can't find the function). This way, the function ResetPlayer could stop being static. But I'm not sure if this is right, since I can't get it without compile errors.

EDIT2: It worked, even though I had to put it one liner

```js
hitInfo.gameObject.GetComponent(PlayerControlHS).ResetPlayer();
```

Because Unity was telling me that I needed to put a semicolon here (I don't understand :S):

```js
PlayerControlHS playerScript ; = hitInfo.gameObject.getComponent(PlayerControlHS);
```

But I still can't get to modify the variables of the position...

I have tried fixing it but I get an error saying that "I need an instance of type UnityEngine.Component to access non static member 'rigidBody2D' in a variable declaration I made

```js
static var test : PlayerControlHS = rigidbody2D.GetComponent(PlayerControlHS);
```

And the code I'm trying in ResetPlayer:

```js
test.GetComponent(PlayerControlHS).rigidbody2D.position.x = test.GetComponent(PlayerControlHS).resetPosX;
test.GetComponent(PlayerControlHS).rigidbody2D.position.y = test.GetComponent(PlayerControlHS).resetPosY;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
PlayerControlHS.ResetPlayer();
```

To this:

```
PlayerControlHS playerScript = hitInfo.gameObject.getComponent(PlayerControlHS);
playerScript.ResetPlayer();
```

That is how you call a function from another script.

**EDIT 1:**

Sorry I got mixed up with C# even though you are using javascript, I figured out why you got that error. There's a slight difference in variable declaration.

Change the above code to this:

```
var playerScript:PlayerControlHS  = hitInfo.gameObject.GetComponent(PlayerControlHS);
playerScript.ResetPlayer();
```

As for resetting the player's position, the script is inside the player game object is it not? Then you can just simplify it like this:

```
function ResetPlayer () {
    rigidbody2D.position.x = resetPosX;
    rigidbody2D.position.y = resetPosY;
}
```

Really sorry for that :(

Comment: what do you mean by one liner?

Comment: I updated the main post because it was too long for a reply. Thanks.

Comment: nice one. please consider accepting my answer if it worked :)

Comment: It partially worked, I still have the problem of modifying the position of a player. Do you know how could it be done in a clean way?